# PHP 5.4 errors in sessions check

Tags: php, mysql, session

I'm building a small admin panel in PHP.
My server is 5.4 version and I've few problems to do it... here's the code:

PHP SCRIPT FOR CHECK IF THE ACCOUNT IS VALID

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$connessione=mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
  mysql_select_db('albo');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']); 
$password=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
 $query = "SELECT * FROM amministrazione WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password' ";
 $ris = mysql_query($query, $connessione) or die (mysql_error());
 $riga=mysql_fetch_array($ris); 

$cod=$riga['username'];
if ($cod == NULL) $trovato = 0 ;
else $trovato = 1; 

if($trovato === 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']='OK';

   echo '<script language=javascript>document.location.href="logout.php"</script>';

} else {
 echo '<script language=javascript>document.location.href="index.html"</script>';

}
}
?>
```

THE PROTECTED PAGE THAT ONLY REGISTERED MEMBER CAN ENTER IN:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_login'] = 'OK')){
        echo "welcome to protected page.";
    }
    else {  
        header('location:login.php');
        die;     
    }
    ?>
```

The error that I get is:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ',' or ')' in /var/www/admintestscript/memberarea.php on line 3

I don't understand where is the problem and also if my syntax for 5.4 is right.
Thank you :-)
Wish you a great weekend!

Kindly Regards

Comment: You have mixed the mysqli_* and mysql_* functions

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if they gave you what you where looking for.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_login'] = 'OK')){
```

Should probably be be

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_login']) && $_SESSION['user_login'] == 'OK')){
```

Answer (score 2):

You have mixed the **mysqli_** and **mysql_** functions,

Use

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_login']) &&  $_SESSION['user_login']== 'OK')){
```

instead of

```
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_login'] = 'OK')){
```

Comment: Thanks so much guys! Now the code seem to work (for a part), expect for the problem that when I log in it back me to login.php page, so that mean the code say that session is not the exact session for logged user.

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION['user_login']) &&  ($_SESSION['user_login']== 'OK')){
        echo "welcome to protected page.";
    }
    else {  
        header('location:login.php');
        die;     
    }
    ?>

I go to login.php instead get the message "WELCOME TO PROTECTED PAGE". I really don't understand what happeaning! :-( Any idea?

Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: if you included ` if(isset($_SESSION['user_login']) && ($_SESSION['user_login']== 'OK'))` this code in your all page it checks the login and show the welcome page, if you want to go login, you need to use `unset($_SESSION);` to clear the session or if you want to destroy all the session then use session_destroy();

Comment: Yes I know, but the problem is that the page where I put the code for check login, result as not logged because it redirect me to the login page instead show welcome message.I think there is something of wrong in the session creation. I'm trying to fix it but I have no idea of what happeaning. Any suggestion? THANK yOU SO MUCH!